# Did Gauss work on the theory of optical abberations?

Tags: biographical-details

I wonder if Gauss gave mathematical expressions for abberations in some of his optical papers (papers others than his Dioptrische Untersuchungen)? I know that he worked out the theory of Gaussian optics (paraxial approximation), but I ask if he did something else about optics in addition.